# Fail to do binding to image

Tags: silverlight

i have simple class

```
public class A
{
    public ImageSource imageSource
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

page class:

```
Public class page : Page
{
     A a_class = new A();
}
```

And simple silverlight page that contain object type A. 
In this page i have Image that i want to bind to imageSource of A.

So i wrote it and its not working.

```
 <Image x:Name="Image_" Stretch="Fill" 
        Source="{Binding imageSource}"  DataContext="{StaticResource a_class }"/>
```

How i need to write it so it will work fine ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is "not working"?  Are you getting an error?  Is the image not showing?  You don't show any code where you are setting imageSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StaticResource` markup extension doed not access fields or properties of the class that the Xaml is loaded into.   Delete the line:-

```
 A a_class = new A();
```

Instead instance A in a resource dictionary:-

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourApplication.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

     <UserControl.Resources>
         <local:A x:Key="a_class" />
     </UserControl>
     <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
         <Image x:Name="Image_" Stretch="Fill"
             Source="{Binding imageSource}"  DataContext="{StaticResource a_class}"/>
     </Grid>
 </UserControl>
```

Note is you want the Image control to track changes made to the imageSource property you need `A` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.